# How to use a struct with a struct in jnr ffi

Tags: java, c, struct, ffi, jnr

I have the following c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Second {
    int a_number;
};

struct Top {
    struct Second second;
};

void lets_go(struct Top *top) {
    printf("The number is %d\n", top->second.a_number);
}
```

And I want to do this from Java:

```
int main(void) {
    struct Top top = {{8}};
    lets_go(&top);
}
```

I also want to use [jnr-ffi](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-ffi), so I looked at the tests and ended up with this:

```
package structs.playing;

import structs.playing.Program.Test.Top;
import structs.playing.Program.Test.Second;
import jnr.ffi.LibraryLoader;
import jnr.ffi.Runtime;
import jnr.ffi.Struct;

public final class Program {

    public static interface Test {

        void lets_go(Top top);

        public static final class Second extends Struct {               
            public final Signed32 a_number = new Signed32();                
            public Second(final Runtime runtime) {
                super(runtime);
            }
        }

        public static final class Top extends Struct {              
            public Second second;                           
            public Top(final Runtime runtime) {
                super(runtime);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        Test test = LibraryLoader.create(Test.class).load("test");
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime(test);         
        Top top = new Top(runtime);
        Second second = new Second(runtime);
        top.second = second;
        second.a_number.set(7);         
        test.lets_go(top);
    }    
}
```

The problem is that the value of `a_number` is not set at all so I get a junk value in the output, for example:

```
The number is 46645760
```

So how do I get the same as in my C code?

Comment: Why didn't you use `int` in the Java code as well?

Comment: @Shark because an int would not get properly marshalled back to the native code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out (by the way, I am aware that the members should be private and wrapped in properties but I wanted to make the code snippet as small as possible, this is not production quality code)...

If you put a [Pointer](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-ffi/blob/master/src/main/java/jnr/ffi/Struct.java#L1630) member variable into the struct you can use it's memory when you construct the sub-ordinate Struct like so...

```
package structs.playing;

import structs.playing.Program.Test.Top;
import jnr.ffi.LibraryLoader;
import jnr.ffi.Runtime;
import jnr.ffi.Struct;

public final class Program {

    public static interface Test {

        void lets_go(Top top);

        public static final class Second extends Struct {

            public final Signed32 a_number = new Signed32();

            public Second(final Runtime runtime) {
                super(runtime);
            }           
        }

        public static final class Top extends Struct {

            private final Pointer secondPointer = new Pointer();            
            public final Second second;

            public Top(final Runtime runtime) {
                super(runtime);                             
                second = new Second(runtime); 
                second.useMemory(secondPointer.getMemory());
            }           
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

         Test test = LibraryLoader.create(Test.class).load("test");
         Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime(test);         
         Top top = new Top(runtime);
         top.second.a_number.set(8);         
         test.lets_go(top);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

EDIT:
I have spent a little more time looking at the code and my understanding about creating structs has changed slightly.

I believe you are supposed to declare everything about a struct and make it final, because everytime you declare a new Member it registers itself with the struct it is a member of.

There are some helper functions in struct for every use case. The overloaded array() method allows you to register an array of Members or Structs. The inner() method allows you to register a single struct. Otherwise you just define new Member objects and they will register themselves automatically.

For example:

```
struct Second {
    int a_number;
};

struct Top {
    struct Second second;
    struct Second seconds[5];
    int another_number;
    int more_numbers[5];
};
```

Is represented as:

```
public final class Second extends Struct {
    public final Signed32 a_number = new Signed32();
    public Second(final Runtime runtime) {
        super(runtime);
    }
}

public final class Top extends Struct {              
    public final Second second = inner(new Second(getRuntime()));  
    public final Second[] seconds = array(new Second[5]);
    public final Signed32 another_number = new Signed32();
    public final Signed32[] more_numbers = array(new Signed32[5]);
    public Top(final Runtime runtime) {
        super(runtime);
    }
}
```

ORIGINAL:
I believe the proper way to do this is using the overloaded Struct constructor that accepts (Runtime, Struct).
https://github.com/jnr/jnr-ffi/blob/master/src/main/java/jnr/ffi/Struct.java#L129

```
protected Struct(Runtime runtime, Struct enclosing) {
    this(runtime);
    __info.alignment = enclosing.__info.alignment;
}
```

This constructor forces the enclosing struct to share its memory. So in your example I think it would look something like this:

```
package structs.playing;

import structs.playing.Program.Test.Top;
import structs.playing.Program.Test.Second;
import jnr.ffi.LibraryLoader;
import jnr.ffi.Runtime;
import jnr.ffi.Struct;

public final class Program {

    public static interface Test {

        void lets_go(Top top);

        public static final class Second extends Struct {               
            public final Signed32 a_number = new Signed32();                
            public Second(final Runtime runtime, final Struct enclosing) {
                super(runtime, enclosing);
            }
        }

        public static final class Top extends Struct {              
            public Second second;                           
            public Top(final Runtime runtime) {
                super(runtime);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        Test test = LibraryLoader.create(Test.class).load("test");
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime(test);         
        Top top = new Top(runtime);
        Second second = new Second(runtime, top);
        top.second = second;
        second.a_number.set(7);         
        test.lets_go(top);
    }    
}
```

Note the changes to Second's constructor and notice that I passed the Top object to the Second object so it is aware that top is enclosing it. This is not tested, just sharing what I found while I was trying to understand the code.

I think what was happening in your example is that the Second object is allocating its own memory that Top knows nothing about.

If this doesn't work I would recommend looking into doing something like this:

```
public static final class Top extends Struct {              
    public Second second = new Second(getRuntime(), this);                           
    public Top(final Runtime runtime) {
        super(runtime);
    }
}
```

Comment: If anyone figures out how to declare a pointer to an array please let me know. I think it would be a combination of the Struct.arrayOf() method and the Address member.

Comment: DataPoint[] points = Struct.arrayOf(runtime, DataPoint.class, 10);
Pointer data_ptr = Struct.getMemory(points[0]);

Answer (score 2):

When structs are assigned, as in the line

```
top.second = second;
```

in your Java code, the struct is **copied** from `second` into `top.second`, so that they become separate entities in different areas of memory. Later, when you assign 7 to the `a_number` property of `second` in the following line:

```
second.a_number.set(7);
```

the corresponding property of `top.second` is left unchanged, because they are not the same object.

In order to end up with the same results as your C code, try changing your `main` method to this:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    Test test = LibraryLoader.create(Test.class).load("test");
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime(test);         
    Top top = new Top(runtime);
    top.second.a_number.set(8);         
    test.lets_go(top);
}
```

Initializing a new `Second` object is not necessary because the memory was already allocated for `top.second` as part of initializing the `Top` object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Sadly top.second is null though so I get a runtime exception with your suggestion.  Do I need to put an annotation on it or something to tell jnr to construct it for me?

Comment: @kmp Try this line before the line that sets a_number: `top.second = new Second(runtime);` I have no experience with jnr-ffi, only with both C and Java on their own.

Comment: Thanks edwardfanboy but doing that has no difference from my original code